# Cloud Foundry, run-task, simple HelloWorld.java

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

i just want to have a simple Application like Hello World run as a Task on CloudFoundry.

So i want to `cf run-task myapp firstArgument secondArgument`

Is it possible to deploy an app on Cloud Foundry and start this jar like on a linux Console.

```
java -jar simpleApp.jar firstargument seconArgument
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is 100% possible.

1. Build your application & compile it.
2. Package it into a JAR file that can be executed. Test & confirm locally by running `java -jar your-app.jar`.
3. Now `cf push -p path/to/youar-app.jar` your application. The Java buildpack should detect the app & install the software required to run the app.
4. The Java buildpack & CloudFoundry in general expect the app that you push to start & run forever. If your application does not, if it's meant to start and only run for a finite period of time, the app is going to fail to start but that's OK. You can ignore that. After it fails, run `cf stop`.
5. If you have a task that runs for a finite period of time, you need one additional step. Run `cf run-task <your-app> <arg1> <arg2> ...`. The trick is that Java will not be on the $PATH so you need to use the full path to the Java executable, which is `.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java`. For example, if you wanted to print the Java version, `cf run-task your-cool-app ".java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java -version"` (make sure you have the command quoted, escape quotes within the command accordingly).

See this SO post for more background on running tasks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67872218/1585136

Comment: if i try to run "cf run-task your-cool-app .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java -version" i get error Incorrect Usage: unknow flag `e'

Comment: @ASP.NOOB that looks like a quoting issue, sorry. The command to run needs to be quoted. I've updated the command above, please give that a try.