# CloudFoundry App instances - EF Core database migration

Tags: .net-core, vmware, cloud-foundry

I've written a .NET Core Rest API which does migrate/ update the database (using Entity Framework Core) in `Startup.cs`. Currently, only one instance is running in the production environment. It seems to be recommended to run **2 instances** in production.

1. What happens while executing the `cf push` command? Are both instances stopped automatically or do I need to execute `cf stop`?
2. In addition, how do I prevent both instances from updating the database?
   I've read about the `CF_INSTANCE_INDEX` environment variable. Is it OK to only start the database migration when `CF_INSTANCE_INDEX` is 0? Or does CloudFoundry provide the next mechanism: start the first instance and when this one is up-and-running, the second instance will be started?

Answer (score 2):

> What happens while executing the cf push command? Are both instances stopped automatically or do I need to execute cf stop?

Yes, your app will stop. The new code will stage (i.e. buildpacks run) and produce a droplet. Then the system will bring up all the requested instances using the new droplet.

> In addition, how do I prevent both instances from updating the database? I've read about the CF_INSTANCE_INDEX environment variable. Is it OK to only start the database migration when CF_INSTANCE_INDEX is 0?

You can certainly do it that way. The instance number is guaranteed to be unique and the zeroth instance will always exist, so if you limit to the zeroth instance then it's guaranteed to only run once.

Another option is to run your migration as a task (i.e. `cf run-task`). This runs in its own container, so it would only run once regardless of the number of instances you have. This [SO post has some tips about running a migration as a task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67872218/1585136).

> Or does CloudFoundry provide the next mechanism: start the first instance and when this one is up-and-running, the second instance will be started?

It does, it's the `--strategy=rolling` flag for `cf push`.

See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/rolling-deploy.html

I'm not sure that this feature would work for ensuring your migration runs only once. According to the docs (See "How it works" section at the link above), your new and old containers could overlap for a short period of time. If that's the case, running the migration could potentially break the old instances. It'll be a short period of time, just until they get replaced with new instances, but maybe something to consider.

Comment: Steeltoe has [support for running tasks in .NET](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/management/tasks.html) and a [sample that uses it to manage db migrations](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/main/Management/src/CloudFoundry).